# Why does John Ruth dislike the coffee?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-hateful-eight

When *John Ruth* enters the cabin in *The Hateful Eight* he tries the coffee, he reacts, immediately spitting out the coffee and throwing it on the floor complaining about how awful it is.

I'm not sure about this scene, to my knowledge it was *Minnie* who made the coffee. According to *four-horse Judy*, Minnie's coffee is supposed to be pretty good.

For the record, I've seen:
[How come the coffee initially tasted awful?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53048/how-come-the-coffee-initially-tasted-awful) But I am under the impression that we know Minnie made the coffee.

Why does John Ruth dislike the coffee so much even though it's supposed to be good?

EDIT:
My question is different, why does *John Ruth* dislike the coffee and complain about it in the beginning scenes? As one user brought up... it might be a cross-reference to another movie (not mentioned on the other thread). I'm starting to think it's possible an answer might be provided with some evidence to support this.

Comment: Personal preferences may be?

Comment: Not sure there is anything anyone could add to the existing answer which would make this NOT a duplicate of the existing question.

Comment: I feel like this has to be some kind of food trope. wether it be something like villians with bad manners or something pointing out how deranged the character is. It also could be QT reference. I remember disticly the scene in pulp fiction where his own character goes on about not wanting to hear "how good his coffee is".: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QGnWnFWoxA

Comment: @DarthLocke That could be it, will check that out later. QT is definitely known for those types of cross movie references. Like the "red apple" brand (in H8, called manzana roja). Always forget about QTs world-building.

Comment: Despite your clarifications it seems like you're *still* asking the same question as the alleged duplicate, the only difference being that your question is additionally based on the unsupported premise that Minnie made the coffee and it should thus objectively not taste awful, a premise that the other question and its answers explicitly contradict. The other question might also seem more generally about the coffee and thus your's more specifically about Ruth, but it's actually based on the exact same information your's is based on, that Ruth said the coffee is awful.

Answer (score 2):

Having watched the movie a while back, I'm not fresh on the exact way the coffee was presented, so I'm going to assume that there was no additional information based on the answer in the question you linked:

> There's nothing explicitly stated about the coffee in the movie.

This seems to contradict what you say here:

> But I am under the impression that we know Minnie made the coffee.

What do you base that on? If it wasn't explicitly mentioned either way, there is no way to know for sure.

**In universe:**

However, you can look at it using occam's razor:

> Why does John Ruth dislike the coffee?

Because the coffee is dislikable (bad).

That's the easiest explanation. The coffee has been introduced, we know nothing about the coffee, how it was made, not now, not later in a special revelation. All we know is that John Ruth didn't like it. It seems pretty straightforward to then conclude that the coffee is bad.

**Out of universe:**

As the linked answer suggests, this might be a foreshadowing that there is something amiss. Yes, Minnie's coffee should be good. Apparently it isn't... how comes?

Comment: Minnie is kind of talking and putting off making the coffee, when four-horse Judy is finally like "You need to make it already!" (they all kind of agree in unison that she makes the best coffee).

Comment: @Sniff which only suggests that the coffee hasn't been made yet. Given that the outlaws attacked not long afterwards, it's quite likely she never got the chance.

Comment: Yes, likely. Guess we'll never know for sure. I might go back and re-watch that scene. A lot going on, she could have done it in the background.